# How to output most common strings in a text file?

Tags: powershell, search, sorting, processing

**Background**

I have a text file containing a list of databases and entries in those databases. Example text file:

```
Database 1
1. Book about abc.
2. Thesis about abc.
3. Book about xyz.

Database 2
1. Book about xyz.
2. Article about abc.

Database 3
Thesis about abc.
Article about abc.
Book about xyz.

Database 4
Number 1: Book about xyz is included.
Number 2: Article about xyz is included.
```

**Problem**

I want to output the strings (which contain a minimum number of words) which occur most commonly. Example output:

```
Name                    Count
Book about xyz          4
Thesis about abc        2
```

**Notes**

The strings occur within lines. i.e. this is not the same as counting the number of occurrences of a line. Sometimes the required string is prefaced and/or suffixed with something e.g. `1.`, `Number 1:` or sometimes not.

**What I've tried**

I've been using PowerShell. I've tried `get-content .\data.txt | group-object | where { $_.count -ne 1 }` or coming at it from the other way with `get-content .\data.txt | select -unique` but I don't see a way of getting to strings within lines. I have also investigated using `select-string` but I don't know the pattern such that I can define a regex `-Pattern`.

Comment: how do you decide what strings to track?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey all strings with a length of more than three which occur more than once. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: you show that the result is two items but your data shows more 3-word sequences ... so, how do you decide that it should only be those two 3-word sequences and not any of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with in Powershell. Let me know what you think

```
 $database = Get-content -Path c:\temp\database.txt
 $MyArrayList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

 foreach($line in $database){
 $flag = $false
 [Int32]$OutNumber = $null

     if ($line -match "database" -or [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line)) {
         continue

     }
     else {


          if([Int32]::TryParse($line.Substring(0,1),[ref]$OutNumber)) {
          $tmp = $line.Substring(2).trim()
          $MyArrayList.Add($tmp)
          $flag = $true

      } 



        if($line -match 'Number') {
        $tmp = $line.Substring($line.IndexOf(":")+1).trim()
        $MyArrayList.Add($tmp)
        $flag = $true


      }

       if ($flag -eq $false) {
          $MyArrayList.Add($line)

       }



   }

  }

 $MyArrayList   | Group-Object
```

Here's my output

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 Book about abc.           {Book about abc.}
    2 Thesis about abc.         {Thesis about abc., Thesis about abc.}
    3 Book about xyz.           {Book about xyz., Book about xyz., Book about xyz.}
    2 Article about abc.        {Article about abc., Article about abc.}
    1 Book about xyz is incl... {Book about xyz is included.}
    1 Article about xyz is i... {Article about xyz is included.}